# How can I validate my $ currency regex only numbers between 0-9999.99?

Tags: regex

I've written my regex

```
^(\d{1,4}|\d{0,4}\.\d{1,2})$
```

where it only accepts values from 0-9999.99
so the accepted values are: 0, 999.99, 9999, 999.9
but now I would like to have also accepted one "$" in the beginning or the end so
$9999, 9999$, $9999.00, 9999.9$ should also be accepted.

Could I please get some help on this how to adjust my current regex?

Comment: Like `^\$?(?:\d{1,4}|\d{0,4}\.\d{1,2})\$?$` ? or without both sides `^(?:\$?(?:\d{1,4}|\d{0,4}\.\d{1,2})|(?:\d{1,4}|\d{0,4}\.\d{1,2})\$)$` https://regex101.com/r/hmCFTh/1 Or shorted with a negative lookahead `^(?!\$.*\$$)\$?(?:\d{1,4}|\d{0,4}\.\d{1,2})\$?$` https://regex101.com/r/fpqMKJ/1

Comment: Is it PHP? Python? Do you allow `$0$` as a valid match?

Comment: @Thefourthbird yes!!! Thanks a lot, still trying to figure out this regex thing...

Comment: @JohnLong Which one? are `$` at both sides allowed?

Comment: @Thefourthbird I think the second one is better because it does not allow $99.99$

Comment: @Thefourthbird one more thing, what if I want to allow spaces? such as "$ 4999.88" would match as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To not allow dollar signs at both ends, and if a lookahead is supported, you can start the pattern ruling out a dollar sign at the start and at the end using `^(?!\$.*\$$)`

For the match, you can make the dollar sign optional at the start and at the end to match all 3 variations.

```
^(?!\$.*\$$)\$?\s*(?:\d{1,4}|\d{0,4}\.\d{1,2})\s*\$?$
```

The updated pattern matches:

- `^` start of string
- `(?!\$.*\$$)` Negative lookahead asserting not a string that starts and ends with `$`
- `\$?\s*` Match an optional `$` and optional whitespace chars
- `(?:\d{1,4}|\d{0,4}\.\d{1,2})` Match either 1-4 digits, or 0-4 digits and a dot followed by 1-2 digits
- `\s*\$?` Match optional whitespace chars and an optional `$`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ycbAQX/1)

If a lookahead is not supported, you can using an alternation to match either the pattern prepended with an optional dollar sign that would match 2 variations, or match the pattern only ending on a dollar sign that would match the 3rd variation.

```
^(?:\$?\s*(?:\d{1,4}|\d{0,4}\.\d{1,2})\s*|(?:\d{1,4}|\d{0,4}\.\d{1,2})\s*\$)$
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4RVtyi/1)

Comment: one more thing, what if I want to allow spaces? such as "$ 4999.88" would match as well? The little details :)

Comment: @JohnLong If you want to allow optional after the leading $ or before the closing $ you can use an optional non capture group matching the `$` with optional spaces. https://regex101.com/r/TAuV94/1

Comment: very close to what I thought, I meant optional before "$" or also " 4000.88" or "4000    " etc.

Comment: @JohnLong In that case you can make both the whitespace chars and the $ optional https://regex101.com/r/ycbAQX/1 Note that `\s` can also match a newline.

Comment: got it!! you are a regex expert! thanks a lot!

Comment: I really like the answer @Thefourthbird. At first I was a bit puzzled but I can see it works a treat. I couldn't help but come up with a slight alternative using `^(?!\$.*\$|\D*$)\$?\h*\d{0,4}(?:\.\d{1,2})?\h*\$?$`.

Comment: @JvdV Thanks, it is fun to puzzle right :-) I see, you make the number part fully optional to loose the alternation, but you guarantee a digit due to the `(?!\D*$)`. Looks nice right, you can post it if you want.

Comment: It's all about the puzzles =). I'm not going to steal any thunder from your answer here. Have a great evening.

Comment: @JvdV You could even turn the greedy dot in a negated character class to cut a very small amount of backtracking to rule out the double dollar sign. `^(?!\$[^$\n]*\$|\D*$)\$?\h*\d{0,4}(?:\.\d{1,2})?\h*\$?$` https://regex101.com/r/Qtke9u/1 :-)